# PHP fill a table with a array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I can't find the bug. 
I've written a php script that produces a form, filled with an array.
The last line is a input field to add a new item to the array.

My problem is that the last entry of the array is overwritten when I add new one.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$array = array("a");
function printForm($array)
{
    if(!isset($array)){
        $array = array();
    } 

    $out=" <form name='' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'><table border='1'> <tr><th colspan='2'>Namen</th></tr>";
    $out = $out. "<input type='hidden' name='posted' value='yes' />";
    foreach ($array as $m) {
        $out = $out . "<tr><td> </td>";
        $out = $out . "<td>".$m["name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    $out = $out.  "<tr><td> <input type='Submit' value='add' /></td>";
    $out = $out.  "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='' /></td>";
    $out = $out."</table></form>";
    echo $out;
}

if( $_POST['name']!=""){
    array_push($array, $_POST['name'] );
}
printForm($array);

?>
```

any ideas?

Regards Michaba

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean it `overwrites`? You think that on each submit new value will be added to an array?

Comment: In PHP variables aren't remembered between browser requests. Since you're not saving the array in any permanent location, and aren't sending it back to the browser in its entirety, it is simply discarded. You'll have either store it in a session or post all of the values back to the form in order to make this work.

Comment: Ah, ok sorry for that silly question. but how can I store this array in a Session? I will store it to the Database when the list is finished.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Erik that pointin me to the Session.
here is the solution that works for me:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( ! isset ( $_SESSION['myArray'] ) )
{
    $_SESSION['myArray'] = array();
}
function printForm()
{       
    $out=" <form name='' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'><table border='1'><tr><th colspan='2'>Namen</th></tr>";
    $out .= "<input type='hidden' name='posted' value='yes' />";
    foreach ($_SESSION['myArray'] as $m) {
        $out .= "<tr><td> </td>";
        $out .= "<td>".$m["name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    $out .=  "<tr><td> <input type='Submit' value='s' /></td>";
    $out .=  "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='' /></td>";

    $out .=  "</table></form>";
    echo $out;
}

if( $_POST['name']!="")
{
    array_push($_SESSION['myArray'], $_POST['name'] );      
}
printForm(); 
?>
```

lateron i will store the array in the database.

Comment: If you're trying to append to `$out`, use `$out .= ` instead of `$out = $out . ` 

Click here for more info on [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).